# Why is the lisp function evaluating the wrong argument?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I define a function to do repeated function calls:

```
(defun repeat (n f x)
               (if (zerop n) x
                 (repeat ((- n 1) f (funcall f x)))))
```

Now I want to want to apply `cdr`:

```
(repeat (1 (function cdr) '(1 2 4 5 6 7)))
```

I am clearly supplying `n=1`, `f=cdr`, and `x='(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)`. It should apply `cdr` once. This is the error message I get:

```
Error: Funcall of 1 which is a non-function. 
[condition type: TYPE-ERROR]
```

But I have a `funcall` of `cdr`, not `1`.

I am using the free version of Franz's Allegro Lisp.

Comment: Don't edit the question to add the answer, it's already in the answer. If you need to show an answer that's different from the accepted answer, post your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function call syntax in Lisp is:

```
(<function> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> ...)
```

So the expression ...

```
(1 (function cdr) '(1 2 4 5 6 7))
```

... is evaluated as "call the function `1` on the arguments `cdr` and `'(1 2 4 5 6 7)`".

In other words, you have an extra set of parenthesis. Try:

```
(repeat 1 (function cdr) '(1 2 4 5 6 7))
```

Same problem exists in your recursive call.